# How do I @everyone with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to have a simple command like "!hello" to output "Hello @everyone" and ping everyone. The output text is correct, but it doesn't actually ping. The command just shows the text @everyone without doing the mention.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    message.channel.send("@everyone Hello!");

}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "hello"
}
```

I would expect it to output this:

[image: https://gyazo.com/e6c3ea154786639bc7f5663c299d8377]

Actual Result:

[image: https://gyazo.com/d3aea3e7ab24da2235fcdbfc336f0940]

Comment: Does your bot have permission `MENTION_EVERYONE`?

Comment: @Hackinet Yes, it has full administrator powers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, turns out I had:

```
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: True});
```

Once I changed it to:

```
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: False});
```

everything worked.

Thank you for your help everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
message.channel.send("<@everyone>" + "Hello!");
```

Comment: This does not work, neither does the variable. @weegee

Comment: @Jordy337 did you make sure you are running the updated script?

Comment: Yes, I did. This seems like a simple problem, but I guess the answer isn't that simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, your latest one does not work either/.

Comment: @Jordy337 strange. Should work. Are you sure you tried "<@everyone> Hello!".

Answer (score 3):

Citing [discord.js issue #2285](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2285):

> You mention everyone or here with the literal strings @everyone or @here, not a > regular role mention.
>   This is not a bug, but a discord thing.

Comment: Could you give an example of the code for what you are saying? I believe I have tried this.

Comment: Sorry this is just what I found after googling. Seems like you and this guy are trying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [guild.defaultRole](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=defaultRole)

You can mention it like this:

```js
client.on('message', (msg) => {
  msg.channel.send(msg.guild.defaultRole.toString());
});
```

You can check if your bot can mention everyone this way:

```js
client.on('message', (msg) => {
  let everyone = msg.guild.defaultRole;
  if (msg.guild.me.hasPermission(everyone.permissions)) {
    msg.channel.send(everyone.toString());
  } else {
    console.log("I can't mention everyone");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the `everyone` role from `guild.roles`.

```js
const everyone = await guild.roles.fetch("@everyone");
channel.send(`Hello ${everyone}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why, but I remember having to put the role in its own string literal in the `send` call:

```
message.channel.send("@everyone" + " Hello!");
```

Unable to test for myself atm, see if that works.

Comment: mentions of any type do not work in plain text and must be triggerd by eg: msg.guild.defaultRole.toString() or msg.member.user.toString()